How to retrieve and display website URL using flask and jQuery in chrome extension
I'm trying to write a toy chrome extension which will, for amazon search websites, display the site's url in an alert pop-up using a flask server (I'll be doing more complicated python stuff eventually, but can't get the basics working yet).
My manifest file looks like:
{
  "manifest_version":3,
  "version":"1.0",
  "name":"test",
  "content_scripts":[
    {
     "matches":["*://*.amazon.ca/s*"],
     "js":["jquery-3.7.1.js","main.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions":[
    "tabs"
  ]
}

My main.js file looks like:
const u = window.location.toString();

var res = $.ajax({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { name:[u] },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (response) {
    },
    error: function (response) {
    }
});

alert(res);

And app.py looks like:
from flask import Flask,render_template, request, jsonify
import os
  
app = Flask(__name__) 
  
@app.route("/")
def process(): 
    # process the data using Python code 
    data = request.get_json()
    url = data['name']
    return '''<h1>The website is: {}</h1>'''.format(url)
  
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app.run(debug=True) 

# in terminal run:
os.system('export FLASK_APP=example_python_script.py')
os.system('export FLASK_ENV=development')
os.system('python3 app.py')

For testing I run app.py (in VS Code) and I can see that the server is "Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000", then I open Chrome, refresh my extension, and navigate to "https://www.amazon.ca/s?k=dog+toys&crid=1JWPGGDDBFSOE&sprefix=dog+toys%2Caps%2C161&ref=nb_sb_noss_1" (an amazon.ca search for dog toys). Through debugging it looks like the process() function is receiving GET requests instead of the POST requests I'm trying to send in main.js, and therefore can't read in the data I'm trying to send. The error that displays at http://127.0.0.1:5000 is "Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'." An alert pop up window displays on the amazon.ca webpage saying "[object Object]" (instead of "The website is: https://www.amazon.ca/s?k=dog+toys&crid=1JWPGGDDBFSOE&sprefix=dog+toys%2Caps%2C161&ref=nb_sb_noss_1").
My question is different from this question because I'm looking for a solution with flask in Python.
Any help would be very appreciated!
